# Extracting Numbers in Sequential Order from Randomly Ordered Column

Tags: postgresql

I have a single column in my database `qs5` which contains a series of multi-select options 1-4 which can appear in any random order, delimited by a space, e.g. `1 2 4` or `4 1`

I want to extract each of these options into its own column, so that I have resulting columns `qs5c1` - `qs5c4`, so that the above examples would look like

```
|qs5c1|qs5c2|qs5c3|qs5c4|
|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  1  |  2  |null |  4  |
|  1  |null |null |  4  |
```

This is the SQL I've been using

```
substring('1' from position('1' in qs5) for 1) as qs5c1,
substring('2' from position('2' in qs5) for 1) as qs5c2,
substring('3' from position('3' in qs5) for 1) AS qs5c3,
substring('4' from position('4' in qs5) for 1) AS qs5c4
```

But what I am returned with, using the above data as an example, is this, where it just picks the first character in the string and skips the rest.

```
|qs5c1|qs5c2|qs5c3|qs5c4|
|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  1  |null |null |null |
|null |null |null |  4  |
```

I'm thinking that when it extracts the first character, the length of `qs5` is 1 character smaller than it was previously, but then again that wouldn't explain why the second row is skipping the 1, since the 1 should be in the same place before/after the extraction of 4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you don't `substring()` from `qs5` but the literals `'1'`, `'2'` etc. so of course this can only result in that single character in the literal. If you use `qs5` instead it works as you intended.

```
SELECT substring(qs5 FROM position('1' IN qs5) FOR 1) qs5c1,
       substring(qs5 FROM position('2' IN qs5) FOR 1) qs5c2,
       substring(qs5 FROM position('3' IN qs5) FOR 1) qs5c3,
       substring(qs5 FROM position('4' IN qs5) FOR 1) qs5c4
       FROM elbat;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=0f9066583e7279d2adf4dfbc47dbbd2a)

Answer (score 0):

If it's really a fixed set of values, I would do it like this:

```
select case when '1' = any(string_to_array(qs5, ' ')) then '1' end as qs51,
       case when '2' = any(string_to_array(qs5, ' ')) then '2' end as qs52,
       case when '3' = any(string_to_array(qs5, ' ')) then '3' end as qs53,
       case when '4' = any(string_to_array(qs5, ' ')) then '4' end as qs54,
       case when '5' = any(string_to_array(qs5, ' ')) then '5' end as qs55
from the_table;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/FMR86051

If you need this in a more dynamic way, you can use something like this:

```
select f.options[1] as qs5c1,
       f.options[2] as qs5c2,
       f.options[3] as qs5c3,
       f.options[4] as qs5c4
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
    select array_agg(x.val order by g.idx) as options
    from generate_series(1,4) g(idx)
      left join unnest(string_to_array(t.qs5, ' ')::int[]) with ordinality as x(val,idx) on g.idx = x.val
  ) f
;
```

Online example with 8 elements: https://rextester.com/PMKDW38472

Comment: so it's actually 8, i just shortened to 4 for sake of this example. do you think the case will be ok with 8?

Comment: @ClayCrosby: yes, you can do the same for 8 values. I have added a more generic (but more complex) solution to mapping the elements to the correct column index.